# error with multiple dlookup criteria

Tags: ms-access, duplicates, vba

This code produces a runtime error 3464 for `dlookup` with `matchstr_t`. I can't understand why as `matchstr_v` seems to work fine. Any offers? At the moment all I'm trying to do is use the `dlookup` to flag duplicate start times for appointments.

```
Dim i, j, clientid, therid As Integer
Dim origin_date, apptdate  As Date
Dim slotday, apptype, venue, matchstr_v, matchstr_t As String
Dim slottime As Date
Dim appt(25) As Date
Dim db As Database
Dim rst As Recordset
Dim test As Variant

origin_date = Date
slotday = Me.slot_day.Value
slottime = Me.slot_time.Value
clientid = Me.Client_ID.Value
therid = Me.Therapist_ID.Value
venue = Me.venue.Value
apptype = "continuation"

slottime = Format(slottime, "Short Time")
For i = 1 To 7
    apptdate = Date + i
    If Weekday(apptdate, 2) = slotday Then
    'set up stuff
    For j = 0 To 25
        appt(j) = apptdate + (j * 7)

        Set db = CurrentDb()
        Set rst = db.OpenRecordset("Dummy")

        Debug.Print "[therapist ID] = " & therid
        matchstr_v = "[appt date]= #" & appt(j) & "# AND [appt time] = #" & slottime & "# AND [venue] = '" & venue & "'"
        matchstr_t = "[appt date]= #" & appt(j) & "# AND [appt time] = #" & slottime & "# AND [therapist ID] = " & therid
        Debug.Print matchstr_t
        If Not IsNull(DLookup("[dummy ID]", "Dummy", matchstr_v)) Then
            ' do more stuff
        ElseIf Not IsNull(DLookup("[dummy ID]", "Dummy", matchstr_t)) Then
            ' do more stuff
        Else
            rst.AddNew
            rst.Fields("appt date") = appt(j)
            rst.Fields("appt time") = slottime
            rst.Fields("Client ID") = clientid
            rst.Fields("Therapist ID") = therid
            rst.Fields("appt type") = "continuation"
            rst.Fields("attendance") = "scheduled"
            rst.Fields("venue") = venue
            'Debug.Print rst.Fields("appt date")
            rst.Update
            test = (DLookup("[dummy ID]", "Dummy", matchstr_v))
            Debug.Print test
        End If
        rst.Close
        db.Close
    Next j
    Else
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: Please show us what `Debug.Print matchstr_t` gives you when the error occurs with `DLookup`.

Comment: [appt date]= #27/05/2013# AND [appt time] = #16:00# AND [Therapist ID] = 2

Comment: What happens when you create and test this new Access query? ... `SELECT * FROM Dummy WHERE [appt date]= #27/05/2013# AND [appt time] = #16:00# AND [Therapist ID] = 2` ... you could get error #3464, *"Data type mismatch in criteria expression"* if the data type of `[Therapist ID]` is text instead of numeric.

Comment: Brilliant. Many thanks - [Therapist ID] data type is 'number' in the original table, but when I created dummy to play around with this chunck of code I wasn't careful enough setting data types. Problem solved. I'll work out how to accept this answer/comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the datatype of [therapist ID]?

There seems to be a datatype mismatch with the value of therid.

Comment: [therapist ID] is a field in the table I'm working with- the bound value is an integer.

Answer (score 0):

In that case maybe you are just missing a #

matchstr_t = "[appt date]= #" & appt(j) & "# AND [appt time] = #" & slottime & "# AND [therapist ID] = **#**" & therid

Comment: debug.print matchstr_t gives